# How to find positive rational points for both x and y in $x^3+y^3=1141$?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I did some research about finding a rational solution for this equation
$$
x^3 + y^3 = 1141\ ,
$$
and learned a little about elliptic curves. However, those solutions require a known rational solution. How do you solve this without a known rational solution?

I am able to find $(-19,20)$ and $(20,-19)$ but I need both coordinates to be positive and rational.

Comment: Whole numbers are rational

Comment: Did you mean you need both coordinates to be _positive_ as it says in your title?

Comment: Sorry, both x and y need to be positive and rational

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple way to pass from the given equation to the equation of an elliptic curve in short Weierstraß form. First of all, a rational solution to the given equation $A=x^3+y^3$ is immediately leading via $x=v/u$, $y=1/u$  to one for:
$$
E_{u,v}\ :\qquad
Au^3 -v^3=1\ ,\qquad A=1141\text{ for short.}
$$
We use the substitutions:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
u &= +\frac{6X}{Y+36A}\ ,\\
v &= -\frac{Y-36A}{Y+36A}\ ,
\end{aligned}
\right.
\qquad
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
X &= +12A\frac{u}{v+1}\ ,\\
Y &= -36A\frac{v-1}{v+1}\ ,
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
and pass from the equation $(E_{u,v})$ to
$$
E_{X,Y}\ :\qquad
Y^2 = X^3 -432A^2\ .
$$
For $A=1141$ the curve $E_{X,Y}$ has the following group of rational points:
$$
E_{X,Y}(\Bbb Q)=\Bbb Z\cdot G\ ,
$$
where $G$ is the rational point $G=(13692, 1601964)$ computed below:

```
E = EllipticCurve(QQ, (0, -432*1141^2))
r = E.rank()
print(f'E has the torsion points: {E.torsion_points()}')
print(f'E has the rank: {r=}')
print(f'E has the generators: {[gen.xy() for gen in E.gens()]}')
```

... with the results:

```
E has the torsion points: [(0 : 1 : 0)]
E has the rank: r=1
E has the generators: [(13692, 1601964)]
```

So it is natural to compute some low multiples of $G$, and the corresponding points on $E_{u,v}$:
$$
\scriptscriptstyle
\begin{array}{|r|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & X(nG) & Y(nG) & u & v & \text{positive components?}\\ 
\hline
-5 &\frac{107919499858822483698972}{130671988469474077921} & \frac{1419951486140003132497725950031444}{1493735662882618063636173450031} &\frac{90099894711425518980954732151}{764152273525981384682261984900} & \frac{729583389356636678953911465131}{764152273525981384682261984900} & OK\\\hline
-4 &\frac{1505788158419692}{1557925852561} & -\frac{35882783087287412944556}{1944554753465210809} &\frac{1235415052524024021}{4819429005921295601} & \frac{12681563775265601680}{4819429005921295601} & OK\\\hline
-3 &\frac{56173881}{36100} & -\frac{388326874221}{6859000} &-\frac{7115358260}{11842954469} & -\frac{74451906469}{11842954469} & \\\hline
-2 &\frac{579628}{169} & -\frac{438203332}{2197} &-\frac{4953}{38120} & -\frac{57893}{38120} & \\\hline
-1 &13692 & -1601964 &-\frac{1}{19} & -\frac{20}{19} & \\\hline
1 &13692 & 1601964 &\frac{1}{20} & -\frac{19}{20} & \\\hline
2 &\frac{579628}{169} & \frac{438203332}{2197} &\frac{4953}{57893} & -\frac{38120}{57893} & \\\hline
3 &\frac{56173881}{36100} & \frac{388326874221}{6859000} &\frac{7115358260}{74451906469} & -\frac{11842954469}{74451906469} & \\\hline
4 &\frac{1505788158419692}{1557925852561} & \frac{35882783087287412944556}{1944554753465210809} &\frac{1235415052524024021}{12681563775265601680} & \frac{4819429005921295601}{12681563775265601680} & OK\\\hline
5 &\frac{107919499858822483698972}{130671988469474077921} & -\frac{1419951486140003132497725950031444}{1493735662882618063636173450031} &\frac{90099894711425518980954732151}{729583389356636678953911465131} & \frac{764152273525981384682261984900}{729583389356636678953911465131} & OK\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
We come back to the $(x,y)$-world, and compute the corresponding solutions:
$$
\scriptscriptstyle
\begin{array}{|r|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & x(nG) & y(nG) & \text{positive components?}\\ 
\hline
-8 &-\frac{20197700640338492383064954268566600825502944939084720003781660098370987006401}{2381305545249687781279351690485946649094912277333057869129944426443857745179} & \frac{28702892949049111292455992823667595666172140944311096279912913428625801411360}{2381305545249687781279351690485946649094912277333057869129944426443857745179} & \\\hline
-7 &-\frac{10107111001800429822916755727649148165691949623610770407860}{4440038149850805694297164372288229670320006269351167798801} & \frac{46555479964811694055612989260219480802501737256206366430781}{4440038149850805694297164372288229670320006269351167798801} & \\\hline
-6 &\frac{3251781815449699181565034034351186398064507}{982759974343824034008475397266016512177560} & \frac{10159490447312635405133019202725783999183493}{982759974343824034008475397266016512177560} & OK\\\hline
-5 &\frac{729583389356636678953911465131}{90099894711425518980954732151} & \frac{764152273525981384682261984900}{90099894711425518980954732151} & OK\\\hline
-4 &\frac{12681563775265601680}{1235415052524024021} & \frac{4819429005921295601}{1235415052524024021} & OK\\\hline
-3 &\frac{74451906469}{7115358260} & -\frac{11842954469}{7115358260} & \\\hline
-2 &\frac{57893}{4953} & -\frac{38120}{4953} & \\\hline
-1 &20 & -19 & \\\hline
1 &-19 & 20 & \\\hline
2 &-\frac{38120}{4953} & \frac{57893}{4953} & \\\hline
3 &-\frac{11842954469}{7115358260} & \frac{74451906469}{7115358260} & \\\hline
4 &\frac{4819429005921295601}{1235415052524024021} & \frac{12681563775265601680}{1235415052524024021} & OK\\\hline
5 &\frac{764152273525981384682261984900}{90099894711425518980954732151} & \frac{729583389356636678953911465131}{90099894711425518980954732151} & OK\\\hline
6 &\frac{10159490447312635405133019202725783999183493}{982759974343824034008475397266016512177560} & \frac{3251781815449699181565034034351186398064507}{982759974343824034008475397266016512177560} & OK\\\hline
7 &\frac{46555479964811694055612989260219480802501737256206366430781}{4440038149850805694297164372288229670320006269351167798801} & -\frac{10107111001800429822916755727649148165691949623610770407860}{4440038149850805694297164372288229670320006269351167798801} & \\\hline
8 &\frac{28702892949049111292455992823667595666172140944311096279912913428625801411360}{2381305545249687781279351690485946649094912277333057869129944426443857745179} & -\frac{20197700640338492383064954268566600825502944939084720003781660098370987006401}{2381305545249687781279351690485946649094912277333057869129944426443857745179} & \\\hline
\end{array}
$$
Which is the "next point" with positive components on the given curve $x^3 + y^3 =A$?

As seen from the table,
the symmetry $(x,y)\leftrightarrow (y,x)$ of the given curve corresponds to $nG\leftrightarrow -nG$. So we restrict to $n>0$.
Then the "next point" with positive components is obtained by chance for
$n=14$, and it has the components
$$x=a/d^2\ , \qquad y=b/d^3\ ,$$ where:

$$
\scriptscriptstyle
\begin{aligned}
d &= 13 \cdot 67 \cdot 79 \cdot 229 \cdot 1973 \cdot 4273 \cdot 11801 \cdot 20369 \cdot 999912983 \cdot 7444893961 \cdot 98219876142023 \cdot 26821632623650536155443
\\
&=626230968765064500908406698002163698753726606441611774053929714399243715527427
\\[2mm]
a&=366512605460575637459879550925446959825959721136405443562315244392970531278204356287931431460810492826906889647704298737769629439488179659856286740770212345068
\\
b&=3913269940586688523023028783172102841052906712137213720262934652110477241689555806926413983594233087186943792852425247864207345435773670081587851493680903057701817406317425792305980124580540094215664557964734757891690564577112872034328188
\end{aligned}
$$

---

*Note:*
The above first table was produced via:

```
A = 1141
G = EllipticCurve(QQ, (0, -432*A^2)).gens()[0]
for n in [-5..-1] + [1..5]:
    X, Y = (n*G).xy()
    u, v = 6*X/(Y + 36*A), -(Y - 36*A)/(Y + 36*A)
    ok = 'OK' if u > 0 and v > 0 else ''
    print(f'{n} &'
          f'{latex(X)} & {latex(Y)} &'
          f'{latex(u)} & {latex(v)} & {ok}\\\\\\hline')
```

and the second table, with the same `G`, and some more $n$-values:

```
for n in [-8..-1] + [1..8]:
    X, Y = (n*G).xy()
    u, v = 6*X/(Y + 36*A), -(Y - 36*A)/(Y + 36*A)
    x, y = v/u, 1/u
    ok = 'OK' if x > 0 and y > 0 else ''
    print(f'{n} &'
          f'{latex(x)} & {latex(y)} & {ok}\\\\\\hline')
```

Comment: What programming language is being used here?

Comment: @Somos This is *sage*, www.sagemath.org  - it gives a good (object oriented - a matter of taste) functionality using python as "common language" and a "common world" for a lot of computer algebra systems (CAS). Pari/GP is for instance "parsed" here inside. Especially for the elliptic curve machine, but also sage proper code is added. Your theta-series identities can be (i'd say) easily tested in sage. Modular forms are well supported. If a $-CAS is present on the same machine (e.g. mathematica, maple, magma) - i think there is also a good chance to use it. Issues? Ask on ask.sagemath.org/

Answer (score 3):

A key idea for solving $x^3 + y^3 = 1141$ is point doubling.
I refer to the book by L. E. Dickson,
*History of the Theory of Numbers*, Volume II, Chapter XXI,
section 'Three equal sums of two cubes', pp. $572$-$578$. On
page $572$ "Numbers the sum of two rational cubes: $x^3 + y^3 = Az^3$":

> $\quad$ J. Pretet$^{181}$ employed Fermat's process to get the solution
> $$X = x(2y^3+x^3), \qquad Y = -y(2x^3+y^3), \qquad Z = z(x^3-y^3). $$

Given one solution $\;(x:y:z) = (20:-19:1)\;$ of $\;x^3+y^3=1141z^3,\;$
its double is $(-114360: 173679: 14859)$ which is equivalent to
$(38120: -57893: -4953)$ in homogeneous coordinates.
In order to get both $x$ and $y$ positive
you can keep doubling the points. In fact the next doubling gives
$$(12681563775265601680: 4819429005921295601: 1235415052524024021).$$

All the points $(x:y:z)$ in homogeneous coordinates that satisfy the
elliptic curve equation $x^3+y^3=Az^3$ form an abelian group
with a geometric group law. Doubling a point is a special case of
addition of points. In any particular case, there may or
may not be any positive rational solutions. However, if there is a
non-torsion such solution (as is the case here) then there will be
infinitely many such close to it.

---

In general, the solutions to $\,x^3 + y^3 = Az^3\,$ are given by
generalized Somos-$5$ sequences. In the specific case of $\,A=1141\,$
we know that $\;(x:y:z) = (20:-19:1)\;$ is one solution and others
can be found through doubling and addition of points. Now define the
sequence of points $\,(x_n:y_n:z_n)\,$ through initial values
$$ x_{-2} = 38120,\; x_{-1} = 19,\; x_0 = 1,\; x_1 = 20,\; x_2 = 57803 $$
and the recursion relation for all integer $\,n\,$
$$ x_{n+3}x_{n-2}=7115358260x_{n+2}x_{n-1}-249427630228957 x_{n+1}x_n. $$
Define the other sequence $\,y_n := -x_{-n}\,$ for all integer
$\,n.\,$ Also define $\,z_n := \pm\sqrt[3]{(x_n^3 + y_n^3)/A}\,$ for
$\,0\le n\le 5,\; z_{n} = -z_{-n}\,$ for $\,n<0\,$ and $\,y_n, z_n\,$
satisfy the same recursion relation as $\,x_n.\,$ You can verify  that
$\, x_n^3 + y_n^3 = Az_n^3\,$ for all integer $\,n.\,$

For convenience and as a check, here is a table of sequence values:

$$ \begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|} \hline
  n &&  x_n & y_n & z_n \\ \hline
-3 && 11842954469 & -74451906469 & -7115358260 \\  \hline
-2 && 38120 & -57893 & -4953 \\  \hline
-1 && 19 & -20 & -1 \\  \hline
 0 && 1 & -1 & 0 \\  \hline
 1 && 20 & -19 & 1 \\  \hline
 2 && 57893 & -38120 & 4953 \\  \hline
 3 && 74451906469 & -11842954469 & 7115358260 \\  \hline
 4 && 12681563775265601680 & 4819429005921295601 & 1235415052524024021
   \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Approximately $1/3$ of all points have $\,x_n\,$ and $\,y_n\,$ of the
same algebraic sign as $\,z_n\,$ and thus, the affine point
$\,(x,y) := \big(\frac{x_n}{z_n}, \frac{y_n}{z_n}\big)\,$ satisfies
$\,x^3+y^3 = 1141,\,$ is positive and rational since
$\,x_n, y_n, z_n\in\mathbb{Z}.\,$ These points come in runs of
either three or four consecutive points.

---

The general situation is we want to find rational points $\,(x,y)\,$
of the curve $\,E\!: x^3 + y^3 = A\,$ where $\,A\,$ is a fixed
integer. It is natural to use homogeneous coordinates to modify the
equation to $\,x^3 + y^3 = Az^3\,$ where $\,(x:y:z)\,$ is the
homogeneous coordinates of the point $\,(x/z,y/z).\,$ The set of all
points on the curve $\,E\,$ including the point at infinity $\mathcal{O}$
forms an abelian group using elliptic curve addition $\oplus$.
The negation of point $\,(x,y)\,$ is $\,\ominus(x,y) = [-1](x,y) :=
(y,x)\,$ or $\,(y:x:z)\,$ in homogeneous coordinates. The additive
identity is $\mathcal{O}:=\,(1:-1:0).\,$ The **negative**
of the double of a point is, as given in Dickson,

$$ [-2](x:y:z) = (x(2y^3+x^3): -y(2x^3+y^3): z(x^3-y^3)). $$

Given two points $\,P_1 = (x_1:y_1:z_1)\,$ and $\,P_2 = (x_2:y_2:z_2),\,$
the **negative** of the group sum is

$$ \ominus(P_1 \oplus P_2) := ( x_1 x_1 y_2 z_2 - y_1 z_1 x_2 x_2:
     y_1 y_1 x_2 z_2 - x_1 z_1 y_2 y_2:  
     z_1 z_1 x_2 y_2 - x_1 y_1 z_2 z_2). $$

The group of rational points is finitely generated and may have zero
or more generators with torsion points. The Wikipedia article
[Elliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve) covers
some of the basics. The peculiar appearance of negative of addition
is explained by the result that
$\,P_1 \oplus P_2 \oplus P_3 = \mathcal{O}\,$ for addition
of points on the curve is equivalent to $\,u_1P_1 + u_2P_2 + u_3P_3 =
0\,$ for some constants $\,u_1,u_2,u_3\,$ for the homogeneous point
triples.

Comment: Does repeated doubling always eventually get all positive values? I realize that the successor to an all positive might not be all positive.

Comment: (12681563775265601680,4819429005921295601,1235415052524024021) works. The steps worked out as well. This is crazy. I should look more into the elliptic curve

Comment: Unless this happens to be a rank zero curve, there will be infinitely many rational points with positive coordinates. This is because on a rank $\ge1$ curve the rational points form a dense subset of the real locus. +1 for explaing the process and working out a few points!

Comment: Dan Fulea (+1 to him also) used a CAS to work out that this is a rank one curve so there will be infinitely many positive rational points.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen it's not true in general that rational points are dense in real points, even in the positive rank case. For example if $E$ has 2 connected components over $\mathbb{R}$ it is possible that there are no points in one of the components (this is a manifestation of the Brauer-Manin obstruction to weak approximation).

Comment: Thanks @Mummytheturkey. Yeah, I had in mind a curve with only a single connected component (which is compact leading to an infinite subgroup being dense, IIRC). I'm sadly ignorant about Brauer-Manin :-( And a bit surprised to learn that one component might have no rational points while the other one does. Can you describe an example? Actually that would deserve to be a separate question.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yeah, it's quite long to give an answer to that in a comment. After a quick search, I think (checking computationally) that the first example in the LMFDB is 359.a1 which has rank 1. You can try plotting points with Sage to convince yourself.

Comment: Some code for the above ```E = EllipticCurve([1, -1, 1, -7, 8]); P = E(2,-1); pts = [n*P for n in range(1,500)]; pts = pts + [-Q for Q in pts]; pts = [Q.xy() for Q in pts]; pts = [Q for Q in pts if Q[0] < 6]; show(plot(E) + points(pts, rgbcolor=(1,0,0), pointsize=10));```